# Gmail compatibility for templating

Tags: templates, import, fonts, hyperlink, gmail

I'm using a [mail template](https://codepen.io/ayoubayari/pen/GRjMRVY) that I'd like to use through gmail but I saw on [CanIMail](https://www.caniemail.com/) website that "import":

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

and "link":

```
<link href="https://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
```

aren't compatible, and that's a big problem because I have a bootstrap icon that won't show up to the mail receiver, and he won't be able to see the google fonts I need as well.

Is there any way to overcome this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Gmail doesn’t support `@font-face` for custom fonts either: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/ Even if you inlined the CSS you are using with `@import` or the `link` tag, the fonts (and icon fonts) won’t be used.

If you have everything else working, one option would be to keep the fonts from Google Fonts, but set some fallback fonts for clients like Gmail that won’t use be able to use them. Ex:

```
font-family: Poppins, Avenir Next, Futura, Verdana, sans-serif;
```

Depending on what you’re trying to do, Bootstrap may not work as you expect either—there are some similar frameworks that are specifically written for compatibility with email clients, since some like Gmail still deviate so much from what browsers support today.

If you are only using a small number of icons, you will probably have better luck turning those specific icons into PNG images.

Comment: Thank you @kennethormandy, this is what I ended up doing. I hope google will fix these compatibily issues so we can push our limits in email templating.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?